# What is the name for a simplified street map?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a way to describe the kind of simple road/street map that is pared down to essentials—thin lines for roads, just a few places highlighted, no extraneous detail or color. What is the best way to describe this kind of map?

Comment: Not sure there is a word for exactly what you describe. In general, it sounds like *street map* or *road map* is appropriate. Why don't you provide some context wrt what you do not want displayed, and perhaps why?

Comment: If you don't like my edit feel free to undo. Alternatively, if you do, then if you click the 'edit' button and fiddle about for a bit, my name will disappear from under your question! :)

Comment: Why not "simplified map"? http://www.citylab.com/commute/2013/11/wonderfully-simplified-map-san-franciscos-bicycle-infrastructure/7554/

Comment: A map ala Tufte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[bare-bones](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bare-bones?s=t)* is a good term:

> the irreducible minimum; the most essential components
> *<sub>source: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bare-bones?s=t</sub>*

So you have a *bare-bones map*.